# Can't add data fetched from Firebase to new Array

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm am fetching data from firebase from 3 different collections. Once I have the data fetched I would like to append the data from the 3 functions to 1 new array so I have all the data stored one place. But once I append it comes out empty like the fetch functions didn't work. I've tested and debugged and the data is there but I can't seem to add the fetched data to a new Array.

---

Model

```
 import Foundation
 import SwiftUI

 struct GameModel: Identifiable {
     var id = UUID()
     var title: String
     var descriptionMenu: String
     var imageNameMenu: String
 }
```

---

```
Fetch Data Class

 import Foundation
 import SwiftUI
 import Firebase

 class SearchController: ObservableObject {

     @Published var allGames = [GameModel]()

     @Published var cardsMenu = [GameModel]()
     @Published var diceMenu = [GameModel]()
     @Published var miscellaneuosMenu = [GameModel]()

     private var db = Firestore.firestore()

     func fetchCardGamesData() {...}
     func fetchDiceGamesData() {...}   
     func fetchMiscGamesData() {...}

     func combineGames() {
    
         for i in cardsMenu {
            allGames.append(i)
         }
    
         for n in diceMenu {
            allGames.append(n)
         }
    
         for x in miscellaneuosMenu {
            allGames.append(x)
         }
     }
 }
```

---

```
Fetch data Functions

func fetchCardGamesData() {
     db.collection("cardsMenu").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
         guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
        
        self.cardsMenu = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> GameModel in
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
            
            let descriptionMenuRecieved = data["descriptionMenu"] as? String ?? ""
            let descriptionMenu = descriptionMenuRecieved.replacingOccurrences(of:         "\\n", with: "\n")
            
            let imageNameMenu = data["imageNameMenu"] as? String ?? ""
            
            let allGameInfo = GameModel(title: title, descriptionMenu:         descriptionMenu, imageNameMenu: imageNameMenu)
            
            return allGameInfo
        }
    }
 }
```

---

```
func fetchDiceGamesData() {
    db.collection("diceMenu").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
        
        self.diceMenu = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> GameModel in
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
            
            let descriptionMenuRecieved = data["descriptionMenu"] as? String ?? ""
            let descriptionMenu = descriptionMenuRecieved.replacingOccurrences(of:     "\\n", with: "\n")
            
            let imageNameMenu = data["imageNameMenu"] as? String ?? ""
            
            let allGameInfo = GameModel(title: title, descriptionMenu:     descriptionMenu, imageNameMenu: imageNameMenu)
         
            return allGameInfo
        }
        
    }
 }
```

---

```
     func fetchMiscGamesData() {
    db.collection("miscellaneuosMenu").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error)     in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
        
        self.miscellaneuosMenu = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) ->     GameModel in
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
            
            let descriptionMenuRecieved = data["descriptionMenu"] as? String ?? ""
            let descriptionMenu = descriptionMenuRecieved.replacingOccurrences(of:     "\\n", with: "\n")
            
            let imageNameMenu = data["imageNameMenu"] as? String ?? ""
            
            let miscellaneousGames = GameModel(title: title, descriptionMenu:     descriptionMenu, imageNameMenu: imageNameMenu)
            return miscellaneousGames
        } 
    }
 }
```

---

```
View
import SwiftUI
 import Foundation

 struct SearchView: View {

    @ObservedObject var allGames = SearchController()

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView{
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                GeometryReader{_ in
                    //Text("Home")
                }
                .background(Color("Color").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            
                SearchBar(data: self.$allGames.allGames)
                    .padding(.top)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Search")
            .padding(.top, -20)
            .onAppear(){
                self.allGames.fetchCardGamesData()
                self.allGames.fetchDiceGamesData()
                self.allGames.fetchMiscGamesData()
                self.allGames.combineGames()
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
 }
```

---

SearchBar

```
struct SearchBar: View {

@State var txt = ""
@Binding var data: [GameModel]

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(spacing: 0){
        
        HStack{
            
            TextField("Search", text: self.$txt)
            
            if self.txt != "" {
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    self.txt = ""
                    
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                })
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }.padding()
        
        if self.txt != ""{
            
            if self.data.filter({$0.title.lowercased().contains(self.txt.lowercased())}).count == 0 {
                Text("No Results Found")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                    .padding()
            }
            else {
                
                List(self.data.filter{$0.title.lowercased().contains(self.txt.lowercased())}){
                    i in
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: i.view.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline).onAppear(){
                        // Clear searchfield when return
                        txt = ""
                    }) {
                        Text(i.title)
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3)
                .padding(.trailing)
            }
        }
    }
    .background(Color.white)
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .padding()
}
```

}

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `fetchCardGamesData`, `fetchDiceGamesData`, and `fetchMiscGamesData` functions have asynchronous requests in them. That means that when you call `combineGames`, none of them have completed, so you're just appending empty arrays.

In your situation, the easiest would probably be to make `allGames` a computed property. Then, whenever one of the other `@Published` properties updates after their `fetch` methods, the computed property will be re-computed and represented in your `SearchBar`:

```
class SearchController: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var cardsMenu = [GameModel]()
    @Published var diceMenu = [GameModel]()
    @Published var miscellaneuosMenu = [GameModel]()
    
    var allGames: [GameModel] {
        cardsMenu + diceMenu + miscellaneuosMenu
    }
}
```

Note there's no longer a `combineGames` function, so you won't call that anymore.

Comment: I've added the computed property and I'm getting an error in my SearchView "Cannot assign to property: 'allGames' is a get-only property". How do I get the data from SearchController to SeachView to get to SearchBar

Comment: Since you didn't include `SearchBar`, I didn't realize it needed write access to `allGames`. Normally in a search bar you *filter* the data based on a search criteria. Perhaps that's what you should be doing? I can provide a different solution if not, but it seems funny to mutate `allGames` based on what is being searched...

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot. I've added the SearchBar now in the post.

Comment: You don't ever mutate `data`. Just remove the `@Binding` before the declaration and don't use `$` at the call site: `SearchBar(data: self.allGames.allGames)`

Comment: Well I would Love to see you take. I am very new to Swift and SwitUI so I'm still just learning as I go along.

Comment: Well that makes very good sense and it works now. 
Thanks alot :)